# Update all the tables in a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

When a user changes his username, I need all the tables to updated to replace his old name with his new one.

I have tried:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE * SET UserName='".$username2."'
                 WHERE UserName='".$username."'");
```

But this appears to have only changed one table ( I don't know why it picked this specific table; it is not the first or the last in alphabetical sorting order). I tried more than once and the same table kept changing.

Comment: This is why the username should be in one table, with an opaque identity value used everywhere else.  In your current design, you will have to update each and every table manually.

Comment: @Joe Both are good ideas. How would I set yours up?

Comment: You cannot do what you're trying to do here.. as Joe said, you shouldn't be duplicating the username value in each table anyways.

Comment: As Joe and Connor Suggested you should have maintained user details in one table nad used the user ID(primary key) as foreign key in all related tables. If you can not change this. Then the next best option for you is triggers, refer to this doc online http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Comment: @TAAPSogeking you'd hvae a table of IDs and usernames.  In all your other tables, you'd reference the user by ID.  That number wouldn't change even if the user changed  his/her ID.

Comment: You can do what you want by writing a stored procedure that generates dynamic SQL using `information_schema` to find all the table names. I'm not going to try and write it for you. Give it a try, and come back if you have problems.

Comment: @Joe I was hoping you meant some kind of reference variable; IDs take an extra step when displaying the username

Comment: @TAAPSogeking This is more likely what you need to be doing `$con->mysqli_query("UPDATE yourTable SET UserName = '$username2' WHERE UserName = '$username' ");` and if you have multiple queries, you could use `mysqli_multi_query` and probably using both `ON` and `JOIN`

Comment: @TAAPSogeking I don't know if this will work `$tables = array('table1','table2'); foreach($tables as $table){ db.execute("UPDATE SET UserName = '$username2' WHERE UserName = '$username' "+$table); }`

Comment: @TAAPSogeking Here's something I pieced together, but not sure it will work. However looking up **"INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES"** may help you. `$con->query("UPDATE * SET UserName = '$username2' WHERE UserName = '$username' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'your_database' ");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all,
Why would you have 'usename' stored at multiple places ? Its a bad design.

If you still had to do it, then use Primary Key - Foreign Key relation. And on update cascade option.
See Here:   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Another option is to have Triggers. So that when you update a table in question, the trigger fires and it can perform whatever task you have assigned.
See Here:   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: 1st line was a comment.. 2nd is good answer...3rd is not understandable